# Can't increase Ubuntu partition size

Tags: partitioning

I wanted to move some space from sda2 to sda5, but when I reduced space in sda2 there appeared an unallocated space which I couldn't use when I tried to resize sda5 (sda5 was unmounted) in gparted. What am I missing?

[gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swntM.jpg)

Comment: Try expanding sda3 first. Then resize sda5 which lives inside sda3. You will need to use gparted from a live USB. Boot from live USB. Use try Ubuntu without installing option in the live USB.

Comment: I ran Ubuntu from USB, but there is still a key next to sda3, so it's probably mounted. What should i do?

Comment: Since you boot from usb, you need to boot from another device to use gparted, another usb or cd with live ubuntu. Then run grub and resize-move partitions.